# Change the color of button on alternative click

Tags: android-button

I want the button when pressed once should show black color and when i press it again it should show white color. 
I tried this 
     `button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`
But it changes the color back when the button is released.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a counter and initialize it with zero.
Now for every click, increment it and after increment, check

```
if(counter%2==0) 
     //set color=white
else
    //set color=black.
```

I hope it helps.